# How do I change the color of the background of a 3d object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I don't know how to change the background from white.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The background is not a part of the extruded text. Color the background to what you want after selecting its layer.

In the following example The background layer has got some random content after extruding the text layer. The text layer has "TEXT IN 3D"

[image]